# C++: How to prevent template to specialize a pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I start apologising if I am stupid enough to not find the answer if it is so obvious.

I have seen dozens of pages talking about having specific template specialization for *pointer* parameters.

I'd like to be able, though, of preventing a template to specialize pointer parameters, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
template< class T >
void function( T arg )
{
  //...
}

int main( )
{
    int i = 42;

    function( i );    // Ok
    function( &i );   // Die bastart with a compiler error!
}
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: When you have access to c++11, you can just use static_assert

Comment: Shouldn't it be `template <class T>`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can declare the specialization(in this case it's technically just an overload) but not define it :)

```
template<typename T >
void function( T arg )
{
//...
}

template<typename T >
void function( T* arg ); //no definition

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    function( i );    // Ok
    function( &i );   //ERROR
}
```

Comment: @daknøk: It's a compiler error, because it's a template. The definition of the template should be in the same translation unit (source file). The linker knows nothing about templates. The compiler is responsible for template instantiation, and it can't do it without the definition

Comment: +1 Hah, of course, that easy! Why do I always want to do it the hard way?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: No, it's a [linker error](http://ideone.com/so8Gp). A function template *specialisation* is (more-or-less) just like any other function, and does not have to be defined in the same translation unit(s) that it's used in.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I wouldn't be brave enough to assert that it's definitely a compiler error, since my assumption is based on my understanding of templates rather than a specific rule, but I can assure you that the definition of a function template ***must*** appear in the same translation unit. (ignoring the infamous **export**)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: A specialization can be defined in a separate translation unit, sure, but it should be defined in the same translation unit in which it is used. What I mean is that if you add to this example another source file with the definition of f that takes T*, you'll still get an error

Comment: @MikeSeymour: You appear to be right about it being a liker error though. At least on two compilers I tested. But that is still weird for me, the compiler could have detected it itself, without resorting to the linker...

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: Sorry, my mistake - I missed the fact that it was still a template. However, it's still a linker error, which would be resolved if a specialisation for `int*` were defined in another translation unit.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Is this even a specializtion? Both templates are function templates, and function templates don't have partial specialization. It appears to me as an overload similar to the example in 14.8.3/4.

Comment: There are two issues with this solution. The first, with the solution it self, is that it triggers a linker error, rather than a compiler error. SFINAE would be the way to go to obtain a compiler error. The second issue is not with the solution but with the answer, the terminology is incorrect. You **cannot** partially specialize a template function. What you are doing is declaring a different base template function that will be a better overload for pointers.

Comment: @MSalters: Indeed, I was getting function-template overloads muddled with class-template partial specialisations.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I believe I have mentioned in my answer that it's an overload rather than specialization, have I not?

Comment: ...as a comment inside parenthesis and yet you leave *specialization* even if you know it isn't? I know you know what it is, but that *specialization* in the sentence means that other people that don't know better will call this *specialization* without paying much attention to the fact that it is not.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: My answer is aimed to help the OP in his practical problem. The terminology is in my opinion a secondary issue, although I can understand the opposite position as well.

Comment: @David, have you considered just fixing the mistakes in this answer? You have sufficient reputation, and this site *is* a wiki.

Comment: @Rob: I really don't believe they're mistakes per se. Indeed, I'm well aware of the correct terminology, but I chose (and still do) to provide the answer I did. I think it's more intuitive for intermediate C++ users.

Answer (score 14):

In C++11, you can use `static_assert` in a way like this:

```
template<class T>
void func(T arg) {
  static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>::value,
                "The argument to func must not be a pointer.");
  // Do something after the static_assert.
  // Now you are sure that T isn't a pointer.
}
```

An example can be found [here on Ideone](http://ideone.com/2TtGx).

I recommend this because it will give more useful error messages when somebody tries to call your function with a pointer (linker errors can be very confusing in this case). Also, linker errors will not show up before linkage occurs.

Answer (score 7):

I'm myself a template metaprogramming rookie, but I think

```
template<typename T>
void function(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value,T>::type arg)
{
    //...
}
```

should work, as this function should only exist for non-pointer parameters. Of course this requires C++11 or at least TR1 or boost's type traits facilities.

Comment: +1 I was testing an alternative (that I am a bit more used to):
`template <typename T> typename enable_if<!is_pointer<T>::value>::type function( T arg )`, but yours should also work. (And both trigger *compiler* errors, rather than linker errors)

Comment: Sorry, this won't work. The original poster wanted `function(i)` to compile, but in your version, the compiler cannot deduce the template type `T`. The variant of @DavidRodríguez-dribeas works fine, though. On recent C++ versions, its signature can be reduced to: `template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer_v<T>> function(T arg)`